# Custom (de-) serialize method throws java.io.OptionalDataException

Tags: java, serialization

When I serialize and then deserialize a map.subMap with my wrapping class I will run into a OptionalDataException.

It seems that an OptionalDataException has to do with primitives but in a map I always have object boxed primitives right. So how can I solve this?

EDIT: added synchronized block

```
public class SerializeableSubMap<K, V> implements NavigableMap<K, V>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7002458872266068959L;
    private NavigableMap<K, V> map;

    public SerializeableSubMap(NavigableMap<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    synchronized (map) {
        stream.writeInt(map.size());
        Iterator<Entry<K, V>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
        Entry<K, V> next;

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            next = itr.next();
            stream.writeObject(next.getKey());
            stream.writeObject(next.getValue());
        }
    }
    //stream.close();
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        int size = stream.readInt();
        map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<K, V>();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            try {
                // get OptionalDataException here!
                map.put((K) stream.readObject(), (V) stream.readObject());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    // delegate map interface methods to map object
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    synchronized (map) {
        int s =  map.size();

        stream.writeInt(map.size());
        Iterator<Entry<K, V>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
        Entry<K, V> next;

        int i=0;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            next = itr.next();
            stream.writeObject(next.getKey());
            stream.writeObject(next.getValue());
            i++;
        }

        if (s != i) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }
    //stream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason i could think of is the concurrent modification to the Map. Say what happens when there is a delete after the following statement is executed?

```
stream.writeInt(map.size());
```

Say initially when the Map size is retrieved, the number of elements present in the map is 2, but say some other thread concurrently removes one of the elements in the map, so now the number of elements present in the map is 1. then what gets written in the stream is only one key-value pair (2 objects).

But interestingly what we read in the reading size is that 2 key-value pairs (4 objects), since we read the size as 2, we try to consume 2 key-value pairs even though what is written is just one key-value pair.

This is something we have experienced with many customers in the field. Later all turned out to be a concurrent modification issue. So I recommend you to check the same.

The Javadoc for the entrySet doesn't confirm that any modifications will throw a concurrent modification exception.

> [Set> entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)
>
> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Comment: hmm the exception still throws up even if I wrap the serialization in a synchronized block (see edit)

Comment: No, not this way.. this will not avoid caller's from modifying the Map. can you add debug points either in the JDK's corresponding Map classes (especially in removal) or in your application where-ever this map is accessed. Alternatively you can add debug point in the writeObject() method inside while to keep on checking the size of the map. Does this issue happen intermittently? or happens always?

Comment: Is it possible for you to put the exception trace? how many objects present in the Map? Is it possible for you to write the serialized content into the file and share me that?

Comment: I have compared the hasCode before and after serialisation. but the hashCode is the same after the exception.

Comment: maybe the key or value objects are making trouble because mostly the implementation works. but fail always on the same piece of code

Comment: Can you add a counter in the writeObject() method to count the number of elements that you write actually and then print the same? Match the same with the size of the map, and then what stream.readInt() returns on the readObject() method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79952/discussion-between-kic-and-sathish).